# mongo query - return the values of field 1 where value of field 2 is x

Tags: mongodb

I want to return only the NAME values where DOCUMENT ID = 10

Below is my data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "DOCUMENT ID" : 10, "NAME" : "Peter", DATE" : "01/1/2016" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "DOCUMENT ID" : 10, "NAME" : "Mary", DATE" : "02/1/2016" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "DOCUMENT ID" : 10, "NAME" : "Kate", DATE" : "03/1/2016" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "DOCUMENT ID" : 20, "NAME" : "Bob", DATE" : "03/1/2016" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "DOCUMENT ID" : 20, "NAME" : "Sam", DATE" : "03/1/2016" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "DOCUMENT ID" : 30, "NAME" : "Jenny", DATE" : "03/1/2016" }
```

Here is the query I tried to run:

```
db.collection.find({"DOCUMENT ID":10},{"NAME"})
```

This is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

How can I write the query so that it will give me just the names where the ID is 10?

Comment: db.collection.find({"DOCUMENT ID":10},{"NAME":1,_id:0})

Comment: This worked `db.collection.find({"DOCUMENT ID":10},{"NAME":1})`. It returns the names and the object id. I suspect that you edited answer to try to remove the object id, so it would just return the name using `db.collection.find({"DOCUMENT ID":10},{"NAME":1,_id:0})` . That did not return any results. What can I change to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. Your code works perfectly! `db.collection.find({"DOCUMENT ID":10},{"NAME":1,_id:0})` Thank you